# adding array to PFObject

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, parse-platform, parse-server

I'm trying to add an array to PFObject and i am facing some issues.

I have a class "MeetUps" on my Parse Dashboard.
In it, I have a row "peeps" which i have set its data type to be Array.

Now the array that i am trying to add to "peeps" is an array of contacts -

```
var meetUpGroup = [InterContacts]() 

struct InterContacts{
        let name: String
        let number: String

    init(name: String, number: String) {
        self.name = name
        self.number = number 
    }
}
```

i have tried this method:

```
    let meetUp = PFObject(className: "MeetUps")
    for i in meetUpGroup as [AnyObject]{
        meetUp.addUniqueObject(i, forKey: "peeps")
    }
    meetUp.saveInBackground()
```

for the above, the error was: **cannot convert value type 'PFObject' to type '[AnyObject]' in coercion**. and the reason why i cast it to [AnyObject] was because an earlier error message prompted me to do so.

I have also tried this:

```
meetUp["peeps"] = meetUpGroup
```

it did nothing.

What am I doing wrong? Please advice on how to save an array onto Parse. Thanks!

Comment: It's not clear what you tried. When you say you tried `meetUp["peeps"] = meetUpGroup`, was that in addiction to the four lines above or instead of it? Please note that Parse will be deprecated by January, and thus is not a good platform to invest in. Firebase is a great alternative.

Comment: dont listen to Acoop, parse is open source now, he doesnt know what he is talking about and it will live maybe longer than Firebase. Regarding your problem, have you checked the documentation? The answer is there https://parseplatform.github.io//docs/ios/guide/#arrays

Comment: @MazelTov thanks for replying. yes, i have checked the documentation. in fact, i based my code on it. but maybe i got something wrong which i can't seem to identify. is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: @Acoop the line you are talking about is not an addition. it's another method which i tried. :/ any idea what went wrong?

Comment: also, @MazelTov, i just tried --- meetUp["peeps"] = appUsers --- appUsers is an array of strings, and it managed to log onto the dashboard. so my question is, do you have any idea why it doesn't accept array of "InterContacts" - a struct i came up myself?

Comment: I think the array in parse can hold only strings, i think you could create a new class with your required data and store in the array only those objectId